# The error: "mount: only root can do that" while mounting a partition

Tags: mount, permissions

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 along with Windows 8.1. When I tried to open the C: drive in Ubuntu a window is popping out saying to run this command:

```
mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda2 /media/2A36EE3236EDFEA7
```

After running the command I'm getting the error `mount: only root can do that`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use (note `sudo` in front)

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda2 /media/2A36EE3236EDFEA7
```

If in future, a program informs you that "only root can do that", "root access required", "super user required", "Permission denied", or similar permissions based problems, you should try sticking `sudo` in front of the command you're executing.

---

#### Mounting a device like Nautilus

If you just want to mount a device from the command line, like it would be mounted if you clicked its icon in the Nautilus sidebar, you can use this command:

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/<device>
```

replacing `<device>` with your device. This doesn't requrire root access, *however* will only allow you to do a *safe* mount, i.e. without any custom mount options and mounting to `/media/$USER/<device>` *only*.

Answer (score 5):

In case you want to mount a partition as a non-administrative user without the sudo command you could also do so with [`udisks`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/udisks). This allows mounting of partitions (or files) in the `/media/<drive_identifier>` directory.

Usage:

```
udisks --mount /dev/<sdxX>  ## to mount
udisks --unmount /dev/<sdxX> ## to unmount
```

Replace `<sdxX>` with your drive's device number. You can only safely mount Windows partitions when they were not hibernated.

Comment: `udisks` will actually mount at `/media/<device>`. Use `udisksctl mount -b /dev/<sdxX>` to mount to `/media/$USER/<device>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try sudo!
For running commands as root, you must use the command "sudo"  before the other commands